# Magento add coupon code to discount on invoice

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

i have a question. I want to show the coupon code on the invoice like this.

Discount (hau723) : -50

Now it is this.

Discount : -50

I have a code

```
if($order->getGiftcertCode()!=""){
    $this->y -= 0;
    $page->drawText('Code: '.$order->getGiftcertCode(), 400, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
}
```

It shows the right code but not with the discount. It looks like this

Discount : -50
Price : 0
Code : hau723

I hope someone can help me, I googled but couldn't find the answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this way **but after it works you have to override this file**

From

```
app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Default.php
```

in

```
getTotalsForDisplay() Method


public function getTotalsForDisplay()
{
    $amount = $this->getOrder()->formatPriceTxt($this->getAmount());
    if ($this->getAmountPrefix()) {
        $amount = $this->getAmountPrefix().$amount;
    }      
    if($this->getTitle()=="Discount") // **custom code start**
    {
      $label = Mage::helper('sales')->__($this->getTitle()) . '('.$this->getOrder()->getData('coupon_code').')'.  ':';  
    }
    else
    {
       $label = Mage::helper('sales')->__($this->getTitle()) . ':';  
    }                                        
//       custom code End

$fontSize = $this->getFontSize() ? $this->getFontSize() : 7;
$total = array(
    'amount'    => $amount,
    'label'     => $label,
    'font_size' => $fontSize
);
return array($total);
}
```

Let me know if you have any query

Comment: It works thanks! But what do you mean by "but after it works you have to override this file" ?

Comment: its my pleasure to help you....Actually this is core file so it will be replace if new magento upgrade so put this file in local directory or first search in google how to override model in magento.

Comment: just search in google how to override model in magento you got lots of article about it

Comment: i think this help you http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/